# Access derived typeid of member var from inside class

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, polymorphism

I have a predator vs prey game that I'm making, which has a Being superclass and *Human*/*Zombie* subclasses. It also has a *City* class with a member array made out of beings that Humans and Zombies will eventually move around in

In the driver I was able to output the beings in a member array of class city using this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            if (city.getBeing(i, j) != NULL)
            {

                if (typeid(Human).name() == typeid(*city.getBeing(i, j)).name())
                {
                    output << "H ";
                }

                else if (typeid(Zombie).name() == typeid(*city.getBeing(i, j)).name())
                {
                    output << "Z ";
                }
                else
                {
                    output << "_ ";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output << "- ";
            }
        }
        output << endl;
    }
    return output;
```

Now I've moved this code to the *<< ostream* overload in the *City* class...

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, City &city)
{
...
}
```

and *getBeing()* is only returning Being typeids. How do I remedy this so it returns appropriate Human/Zombie types? would using a dynamic/static cast be better?

edit:

City member array:

```
Being *grid[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];//holds beings
```

Array accessor:

```
Being *City::getBeing(int x, int y)
{
    return grid[x][y];
}
```

FULL DRIVER AND CITY CLASS CODE:

```
#include "City.h"
#include "Human.h"
#include "Zombie.h"
#include "Being.h"

#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <typeinfo> 
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Zombie;
class Human;
class Being;
void output();

City myCity;

Human human;
Being& being = human;
Zombie zomb;
Being& being2 = zomb;

int x, y, num = 0;



void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true)
        {
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    while (num < 10)
    {

        x = rand() % 20 + 1;
        y = rand() % 20 + 1;

        if (myCity.getBeing(x, y) == NULL)//makes sure spot isn't taken
        {
            myCity.setBeing(&being, x, y);
            num += 1;
        }
        //////////
        x = rand() % 20 + 1;
        y = rand() % 20 + 1;

        if (myCity.getBeing(x, y) == NULL)//makes sure spot isn't taken
        {
            myCity.setBeing(&being2, x, y);
            num += 1;
        }


    }


    timer_start(output, 1000);

    while (true);

    return 0;
}



void output()//this happens each tick
{


//go through array and move each guy
    myCity.move();

    cout << myCity << endl << endl;

}
```

---

```
#include "City.h"
#include "Human.h"
#include "Zombie.h"
#include "Being.h"

#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <typeinfo> 
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Zombie;
class Human;
class Being;
void output();

City myCity;

Human human;
Being& being = human;
Zombie zomb;
Being& being2 = zomb;

int x, y, num = 0;



void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true)
        {
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    while (num < 10)
    {

        x = rand() % 20 + 1;
        y = rand() % 20 + 1;

        if (myCity.getBeing(x, y) == NULL)//makes sure spot isn't taken
        {
            myCity.setBeing(&being, x, y);
            num += 1;
        }
        //////////
        x = rand() % 20 + 1;
        y = rand() % 20 + 1;

        if (myCity.getBeing(x, y) == NULL)//makes sure spot isn't taken
        {
            myCity.setBeing(&being2, x, y);
            num += 1;
        }


    }


    timer_start(output, 1000);

    while (true);

    return 0;
}



void output()//this happens each tick
{


//go through array and move each guy
    myCity.move();

    cout << myCity << endl << endl;

}
```

Comment: What are the definitions of `City::getBeing()` and whatever data structure it uses?

Comment: "beings that Humans and Zombies will eventually move around in", that sounds gory.

Comment: To check dynamically for types you can better use `dynamic_cast`. However, it's even better to avoid the casting by using virtual methods. That's what they're for, mostly.

Comment: @MilesBudnek added code for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: Followup: is `Being` a polymorphic type?  That is, does it declare or inherit at least one virtual function?  If not, `typeid` will not do any dynamic type checking.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Being is the base class for both Human and Zombie, there is a virtual function called move() that is instantiated by both.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I'm not able to reproduce your problem with what you've posted.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I posted my driver and City code. there isn't really anything in the other classes so far so I omitted them.

Comment: You posted the same file twice.  Also, please include all relevant code, including headers.  Refer to the page I linked on how to create a good MCVE.